# How to perform P2P streaming video behind NATs using Java

Tags: video-streaming, p2p

We have an application that uses XMPP to communicate between two clients; a target system and smart phone (Android or iPhone). Both clients use the same account on an XMPP server to find and send messages to each other. This architecture works fine but now we need to setup streaming video (target to phone). Using XMPP is too slow so a peer to peer (P2P) solution is needed. Since both clients (target and phone) are behind local network routers, the solution needs to handle NAT/firewall traversal whereby TCP needs to be used to ensure the packets are delivered in sequence.

Using another public server, we can obtain the global IP address and port of the client's router. This information is communicated between the clients using XMPP messaging. The naive approach is to setup a server socket on the target client using the same port used to access the public server. Thereupon, the phone client is setup to establish a connection with the target client using the target client's global address and port.

The connection is never established. Can anyone tell me the flaw in this approach or suggest an alternate approach that doesn't require a dedicated server?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Ice4j](http://code.google.com/p/ice4j/). It supports pretty much what you're looking for.

Comment: Just know that it is worked on and updated, but there is limited documentation and tutorials....

Answer (score 0):

[Ice4J tutorial](http://stellarbuild.com/blog/article/ice4j-networking-tutorial-part-1), but get Ice4J at the new location: https://github.com/jitsi/ice4j

This package allows pretty much exactly what you would like to do.